# WooCommerce хук на удаление из корзины

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на удалить товар из корзины - срабатывал мой хук!
Вот как я делаю:

Прописываю в файл wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_before_cart_item_quantity_zero', 'wordpress_before_cart_item_quantity_zero', 10, 1);

    function wordpress_before_cart_item_quantity_zero($item) {
        global $wpdb;
        global $woocommerce;

        $cart = $woocommerce->cart;

        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $id_product = $cart_item['product_id'];
            $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM wp_block_product WHERE product_id = %d", $id_product);
            $preparing_query = $wpdb->query($preparing_query);
        }

        var_dump($wpdb);
        exit;
    }
```

Пробовал даже add_action а не add_filter:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_item_quantity_zero', 'wordpress_before_cart_item_quantity_zero');
```

Но никакого толку, ибо ничего не срабатывает при удалении товара.

Answer (score 1):

Вы передаете в запрос не существующую переменную

```
$preparing_query = $wpdb->query($preparing_query);
```

$preparing_query выше нигде не определено.
У вас должно быть както так:

```
$preparing_query = $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM wp_block_product WHERE product_id = %d", $id_product);
```

вот еще естьпример как правильно организовать цикл по елементах корзины https://gist.github.com/corsonr/6775121#file-gistfile1-php